# Spring Hibernate: Getting list of objects from a list of unique values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a Customer object and it has three fields: ID (Primary key), Username (Unique key), Email.

I also have a list of customer names, e.g. ["Bob", "Fred", "John"].

How can I get a list of customers, i.e. List<Customer> , where each customer corresponds to its name in first list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a hibernate query

```
from Customer where username in (:namelist)
```

set your `namelist` as parameter of the query, and execute the query, 
then you got the list of customers.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Hibernate Criteria.

```
List<Customer> cust = session.createCriteria(Customer.class)
.add(Restrictions.in("Username", new String[] { "Bob", "Fred", "John" } ))
.list();
```